# Build custom image for CISCO devices

Tags: cisco

Do CISCO devices support custom image building or deploying custom plugins?

OpenWrt has such feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, they don't. Cisco firmware is closed source.

Comment: Although they do support running a surprising amount of things as virtual machines on some platforms. The features depend on the hardware and software platform in question. Those would serve the role of 'plugins' similar to OpenWRT or similar.